# How to write after a figure in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to type after creating a figure. I have tried doing clearpage but it will just create a new page for the new section and move the figure back a page as well. I just want text, figures, then text. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
\section{exponents}
sklfjsadlkfjskldfjsldkfjaslkfj;klsaj;sjf;lkasj
\begin{figure}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \centering
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=1000,width=.5\textwidth,
    legend pos=north west,]
    \addplot [domain=0:10, color=blue, thick]   {5*x};
    \addlegendentry{5x}
    \addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=red, thick]   {x^2};
     \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
    \addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=black, thick]   {2^x};
     \addlegendentry{$2^x$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{fig:plot1}}
    
    \vspace{3cm}
    
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
    
    \hline
    n & 5x & $x^2$ & $2^n$  \\ 
    \hline
    3 & 15 & 9 & 8  \\ 
    5 & 25 & 25 & 32  \\ 
    7 & 35 & 49 & 128  \\ 
    9 & 45 & 81 & 512  \\ 
    11 & 55 & 121 & 2048  \\ 
    13 & 65 & 169 & 8192  \\ 
    15 & 75 & 225 & 32768  \\ 
  
    
    
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\label{fig:plot2}}
\end{figure}
\section{polynomials}
```

Comment: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144) might be useful here. Probably `\begin{figure}[htbp]` instead of `\begin{figure}` already results in the expected placement. Apart from that, you might want to consider removing all the `\vspace` commands and probably place plot and table side by side to save even more space.

Comment: Your situation is not reproducible  with the fragment of code what you show,  but I suspect that some text before plus picture+table + 5cm of vertical space all in one unbreakable float is simply too much to allow also start a section after it (note that sections headers also have their own rules: they don't like to be in the last and  penultimate rows.)

Answer (score 2):

As @leandriis has already pointed out in a comment, removing the `\vspace` directives, providing the [htb] placement specifier for the `figure` environment, and placing the `tabular` environment next to instead of below the `tikzpicture` environment are all worth doing. In addition, you may also want to assign a `table`-caption rather than a `figure`-caption to the tabular material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,caption}
\begin{document}

\section{exponents}
bla bla bla 

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=1000,width=0.9\textwidth,
    legend pos=north west,]
    \addplot [domain=0:10, color=blue, thick]   {5*x};
    \addlegendentry{5x}
    \addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=red, thick]   {x^2};
     \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
    \addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=black, thick]   {2^x};
     \addlegendentry{$2^x$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{aaaa \label{fig:plot1}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
    \hline
    n & 5x & $x^2$ & $2^n$  \\ 
    \hline
    3 & 15 & 9 & 8  \\ 
    5 & 25 & 25 & 32  \\ 
    7 & 35 & 49 & 128  \\ 
    9 & 45 & 81 & 512  \\ 
    11 & 55 & 121 & 2048  \\ 
    13 & 65 & 169 & 8192  \\ 
    15 & 75 & 225 & 32768  \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{bbbb \label{fig:plot2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\section{polynomials}

more bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! I figured out that the problem was one of the formatting things I was using to try to get latex to do apa format, I think I am just going to write everything up and then figure out how to APA it later.